# Compiling x64Linux2.6gcc file

Tags: linux, compilation, visual-studio-code, data-distribution-service

I am working on a data distribution service protocol using eProsima FastRTPS in Linux (Ubuntu), but I am not able to make it run because **FastRTPS** has  file "**makefile_x64Linux2.6gcc**" which i need to compile but i dont know the commands to do it . I have tried `make` option, too, but still having the same problem. Is there any command for compiling **.6cc file**?

Comment: Any error messages or build output that would help answer this?

Comment: eProsima : https://github.com/eProsima ... ... ... Please edit your question to include "application name". ( `Fast-Buffers` has a file `makefile_x64Linux2.6gcc` ).

Answer (score 0):

You must compile using cmake as indicated in the README file from [eProsima Fast-RTPS github](https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-RTPS)

In you case:

```
$ cmake -DTHIRDPARTY=ON ..
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

You can install in an user's folder setting -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path on the cmake command.

```
$ cmake -DTHIRDPARTY=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/path/Fast-RTPS ..
$ make
$ make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually everything is working fine now. The problem was I was only using `make` command. If I use `make -f`  command it will make an executable file of it.